# usb_cam: VIDIOC_S_FMT error 22

Tags: ros, usb-cam, camera-drivers, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using usb_cam package, I get the following error message:

VIDIOC_S_FMT error 22, Invalid argument

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9098/usb_cam:-vidioc_s_fmt-error-22/) by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13902 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-02-17**:
when you see an answer you like, mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this error on a lot of my student's computers -- try setting the "pixel_format" parameter to "yuyv"-- this fixed it on all computers I've seen.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-16**:
reposting so you can accept the answer.  Working around bug http://askbot.org/en/question/293/how-can-an-admin-answer-own-question-and-accept-it

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-01-16**:
Did not work for me, but that it is because my QuickCam outputs in the YUV420 format, which usb_cam does not support. So if anyone else is trying to use a Logitech QuickCam with ROS, you can get usb_cam working by implementing a YUV420 to RGB conversion (not trival) and adding a YUV420 parameter.

**Comment by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) on 2018-08-06**:
For my Microsoft LifeCam VX-3000 I actually had to set the pixel format BACK to "mjpeg". After that the node starts to spam "[swscaler @ 0x15a5e00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly" but the output works as expected ..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this error on a lot of my student's computers -- try setting the "pixel_format" parameter to "yuyv"-- this fixed it on all computers I've seen.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in my Ubuntu desktop, I have face the same problem and fixed by the following steps...

1. plug in your usb camera to your computer
2. check whether you have installed any other camera apps like droidcam, etc on your system with the command " ls /dev/video* " without the double quotes.. if you see more than one video devices listed on the terminal then remove any unnecessary camera apps from your system with the command " sudo apt-get autoremove droidcam " assuming that you installed droidcam.. it may be any other camera app in your case...
3. check again your camera device by using the command " ls /dev/video* " without the double quotes.. if you steal see more than one video camera listed on the terminal repeat the procedure in step 2... until you see only one camera which you connected to your computer via usb port remains... this fixed my problem and i am happy to share it to those in the same boat with me.,,
   Remember: first of all plug in your usb web camera to your system...

---

Originally posted by [Wessiye](https://answers.ros.org/users/27880/wessiye/) with karma: 21 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [savanadeshra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38818/savanadeshra/) on 2018-12-03**:
Or you can simply go to the launch file and change device name () to one of the available video devices if you are not willing to remove other apps.

worked for me.